# Magento 2 - How to create new language pack for admin interface

Tags: magento2, admin, language

I have successfully created a language package at /app/i18n/vendor/ja_jp and applied it to the storefront.

But the new language package is not appeared in the admin's account setting.
How can I create a new language package for the admin interface?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

then create a module /app/**code**/vendor/ja_jp:

file /app/code/vendor/ja_jp/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'vendor_ja_jp',
__DIR__
```

);

file /app/code/vendor/ja_jp/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="vendor_ja_jp" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
```

and file /app/code/vendor/ja_jp/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\Locale\Config">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowedLocales" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="ja_jp" xsi:type="string">ja_JP</item>
            </item>             
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: are you sure its works for you?

Comment: Sure, this works for any locale in the directory vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data . Working example: https://github.com/karliuka/m2.LocaleRuUA